# i3 How to save background and screen resolution?

Tags: command-line, shell, lubuntu, i3-window-manager

I'm running i3 on a Lubuntu os with very low end specs.
i3 is a great desktop environment, but, every time I log out m y bg picture and screen resolution revert to default.

I was wondering if any one could tell me how to set it so they stay at there current settings.

~Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*i3* is just a *window manager*, it is **not** a *desktop environment*. As such setting the screen resolution or a background image do not fall into the domain of *i3*.

That is not to say there is nothing you can do. You can just add `exec` settings for the commands to your `~/.i3/config`.

- Usually the X.org should find and set the correct screen resolution on its own. If this does not work for you for some reason, you could create/modify X.org's configuration file in order to set the correct resolution manually. If you just want to do the settings from within your X session I would suggest `xrandr`.

  ```
  xrandr --output OUTPUT --mode MODE
  ```

  Where `OUTPUT` is the name of your output and `MODE` one of the availabe resolutions in the format `WIDTHxHEIGHT`. You can get both from the output of `xrandr --query`. For example:

  ```
  Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
  DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 475mm x 267mm
     1920x1080     60.00*+
     1680x1050     59.95  
     1600x900      60.00  
     1440x900      59.89  
     1280x1024     60.02  
     1280x960      60.00  
     1280x720      60.00  
     1024x768      60.00  
     800x600       60.32  
     640x480       59.94  
  DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  ```

  Here the connected output is named `DP-0` and `1920x1080` is the currently set mode. With `xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 1600x900` the resolution could be set to 1600 by 900 pixels.
- There are many programs that allow you to change the background image. If your current choice has a command line interface, you can just use that. Otherwise I would suggest `nitrogen`. It has a simple GUI, that allows you to easily choose and apply desktop backgrounds, and the previously saved state can just be restored with `nitrogen --restore`.

So you could add the following to your `~/.i3/config`

```
exec --no-startup-id xrandr --output OUTPUT --mode MODE
exec --no-startup-id nitrogen --restore
```

Comment: Having set my resolution to `2560x1600` with `xrandr`, everything is now tiny. Is there a way to set like, 2x scaling?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a GUI front end for xrandr to manage the resolution anywhere (Any DE) use arandr.

```
sudo pacman -Sy arandr
```